# Subject verb agreement case

Tags: american-english, british-english, subject-verb-agreement, spoken-english, indian-english

> More than one tree/trees release/releases oxygen even at night.

Can anyone explain me which options are correct in both the cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wasn't sure about your question but I've found [**this**](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/11/21/subject-and-verb-agreement/) very useful entry in the Oxford Dictionaries Blog where your case is specifically explained.

Let me quote an excerpt:

---

> (1) **More than one** in five Britons **are** now classed as obese.

Phrases such as more than one in five /ten etc. can cause problems because people may think the subject is singular. In fact, **the subject is plural** (Britons, not one Briton) so you should use the plural verb **are**.

However, if you use the phrase **more than one with a singular noun**, then the verb should also be singular, even though the underlying meaning is plural:

> (2) **More than one** bathroom in the home **is** definitely an asset.

---

So if we apply what has been exposed above to your case, that matches the second example, it should be

> **More than one** tree **releases** oxygen even at night.